# How to get current logged in user's details using Zend Gdata PHP API?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-gdata, google-contacts-api

I am using following statement to authenticate:

```
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($email, $pass, 'cp');
```

It successfully authenticates the user and I can fetch user's contacts. But I need to fetch the profile details of current authenticated user. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found some help on this link:

http://motyar.blogspot.com/2011/09/fetch-google-plus-profile-picture-using.html

But it requires google profile ID (numeric ID). Is there any way to fetch that ID without implementing oauth?